# How to import variables in xslt style sheet

Tags: html, jenkins, xslt, junit, ant

below mentioned code is a template to generate junit report in .html format. I want to print a path in body section which contains two variables 1. ${buildno} & 2. ${branch_name} . I am new to this scripting and confused how to add it in body section. I request anyone with knowledge in this subject to help me on this code.

Path looks like : XXXX/XXXXX/${buildno}/${branch_name}/report/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
        xmlns:lxslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt"
        xmlns:string="xalan://java.lang.String">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"
  doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" />
<xsl:decimal-format decimal-separator="." grouping-separator="," />


<xsl:param name="TITLE">Unit Test Results.</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="testsuites">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title><xsl:value-of select="$TITLE"/></title>

      <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        var TestCases = new Array();
        var cur;
        <xsl:for-each select="./testsuite">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="properties"/>
        </xsl:for-each>

       </script>
       <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"><![CDATA[
        function displayProperties (name) {
          var win = window.open('','JUnitSystemProperties','scrollbars=1,resizable=1');
          var doc = win.document;
          doc.open();
          doc.write("<html><head><title>Properties of " + name + "</title>");
          doc.write("<style>")
          doc.write("body {font:normal 68% verdana,arial,helvetica; color:#000000; }");
          doc.write("table tr td, table tr th { font-size: 68%; }");
          doc.write("table.properties { border-collapse:collapse; border-left:solid 1 #cccccc; border-top:solid 1 #cccccc; padding:5px; }");
          doc.write("table.properties th { text-align:left; border-right:solid 1 #cccccc; border-bottom:solid 1 #cccccc; background-color:#eeeeee; }");
          doc.write("table.properties td { font:normal; text-align:left; border-right:solid 1 #cccccc; border-bottom:solid 1 #cccccc; background-color:#fffffff; }");
          doc.write("h3 { margin-bottom: 0.5em; font: bold 115% verdana,arial,helvetica }");
          doc.write("</style>");
          doc.write("</head><body>");
          doc.write("<h3>Properties of " + name + "</h3>");
          doc.write("<div align=\"right\"><a href=\"javascript:window.close();\">Close</a></div>");
          doc.write("<table class='properties'>");
          doc.write("<tr><th>Name</th><th>Value</th></tr>");
          for (prop in TestCases[name]) {
            doc.write("<tr><th>" + prop + "</th><td>" + TestCases[name][prop] + "</td></tr>");
          }
          doc.write("</table>");
          doc.write("</body></html>");
          doc.close();
          win.focus();
        }
      ]]>
      </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <a name="top"></a>
            <xsl:call-template name="pageHeader"/>

            <!-- Summary part -->
            <xsl:call-template name="summary"/>
            <hr size="1" width="95%" align="left"/>

        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>





    <xsl:template name="summary">
        <h2>Summary</h2>
        <xsl:variable name="testCount" select="sum(testsuite/@tests)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="errorCount" select="sum(testsuite/@errors)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="failureCount" select="sum(testsuite/@failures)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="skippedCount" select="sum(testsuite/@skipped)" />
        <xsl:variable name="timeCount" select="sum(testsuite/@time)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="successRate" select="($testCount - $failureCount - $errorCount) div $testCount"/>
        <table class="details" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" width="95%">
        <tr valign="top">
            <th>Tests</th>
            <th>Failures</th>
            <th>Errors</th>
            <th>Skipped</th>
            <th>Success rate</th>
            <th>Time</th>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$failureCount &gt; 0">Failure</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$errorCount &gt; 0">Error</xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="$testCount"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="$failureCount"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="$errorCount"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="$skippedCount" /></td>
            <td>
                <xsl:call-template name="display-percent">
                    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$successRate"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:call-template name="display-time">
                    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$timeCount"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </td>

        </tr>
        </table>
        <table border="0" width="95%">
        <tr>
        <td style="text-align: justify;">
        Note: <i>failures</i> are anticipated and checked for with assertions while <i>errors</i> are unanticipated.
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

  <!--
   Write properties into a JavaScript data structure.
   This is based on the original idea by Erik Hatcher (ehatcher@apache.org)
   -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi - No one answered for that question.

Comment: I request you to post the answer if you are aware :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have removed my previous question and updated my code as well. Here I would like to insert the path before summary section

Comment: Is your question on how to find out the var values for  ${buildno} and ${branch_name} ?  Or how to read them into your template?

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if your question is on how to find out the var values for ${buildno} and ${branch_name} or how to read them into your template.  I am going to assume the Jenkins Job will be providing those values and you want to update your template on the fly.  If that is the case, update your template to include `var report_path = REPLACE-PATH-WITH-ACTUAL-PATH`

```
 ...
    function displayProperties (name) {
      var win = window.open('','JUnitSystemProperties','scrollbars=1,resizable=1');
      var doc = win.document;
      var report_path = REPLACE-PATH-WITH-ACTUAL-PATH;
      doc.open();
 ...
```

Then add that var where you want it displayed in the body

```
 ...
      for (prop in TestCases[name]) {
        doc.write("<tr><th>" + prop + "</th><td>" + TestCases[name][prop] + report_path + "</td></tr>");
      }
      doc.write("</table>");
      doc.write("</body></html>");
 ...
```

Before using the template in the Jenkins job, execute a powershell script to replace `REPLACE-PATH-WITH-ACTUAL-PATH` with the desired path.

```
(Get-Content "common/dir/with/the/template.txt") -replace "REPLACE-PATH-WITH-ACTUAL-PATH","XXXX/XXXXX/${buildno}/${branch_name}/report/" | Set-Content "Jenkins/$JOB_NAME/dir/template.html"
```

If you have jobs that will use a common template, but need to insert job specific vars, then create a string in the template that gets searched and replaced before a copy of the template is used in the job.

Comment: Hi david - have tried some code and ran into different issue which I have posted here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59508373/calling-href-in-html-from-javascript?noredirect=1#comment105189402_59508373