# calling href in html from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using below script to create a hyperlink in a .html page and it is successful when I open it in a browser. But when sending that html page through an email body its not getting displayed as hyperlink. Hyperlink for Ant and Junit are working fine in both email body and webpage but Windows, linux & Mac are not getting displayed. Below I have pasted the screenshots taken from browser and email.

Kindly help me to fix this error

```
<td align="left">For detailed results click here    <a id="link">Windows</a> -- <a id="link1">Linux</a><a id="link2">Mac</a>.</td><td align="right">Designed for use with <a href="http://www.junit.org">JUnit</a> and <a href="http://ant.apache.org/ant">Ant</a>.</td>
</tr>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var scrt_var =cur['env.PBCS_VERSION']; 
    var scrt_var1 =cur['env.PBCS_BUILD']; 
    window.document.getElementById("link").setAttribute("href","\\\\slcnas502\\EPM_Planning\\PlanningDev\\Buzz\\tmp_pre_rel\\Planning\\builds\\" + scrt_var + "\\" + scrt_var1 + "\\" + "junit\\report\\html\\");
    window.document.getElementById("link1").setAttribute("href"," /net/slcnas50/export/EPM_Planning/PlanningDev/Buzz/tmp_pre_rel/Planning/builds/" + scrt_var + "/" + scrt_var1 + "/junit/report/html");
    window.document.getElementById("link2").setAttribute("href","smb://slcnas502/EPM_Planning/PlanningDev/Buzz/tmp_pre_rel/Planning/builds/" + scrt_var + "/" + scrt_var1 + "/junit/report/html");
    </script>
</table>
```

[image: Browser]

[image: email body]

Comment: can you please tell me where exactly to use

Comment: The code looks fine. So, make sure that you use the path right and be sure about the beginning and the end and also the current path.

Comment: The path I have given is correct. It works fine when I open it through .html

Comment: Try to use three slashes instead of four and see if it is working.

Comment: Also, you can use different ways to define.See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345427/setting-href-attribute-at-runtime